# Asterisk call failure timeout

Tags: asterisk, telephony, pbx, voice

I am using Asterisk and there seems to be a problem with the delay that the server answers a call. What actually happens is that the caller hears a busy tone and then hangs up, but a channel is opened on the server so after around 20 seconds the phone rings at the fail over destination of the IVR. When the receptionists picks up the phone, there is no one on the other end of the call.

I called my provider and there was a 2 seconds timeout on their call transfer. I asked them to remove it, and the problem seemed solved. I was contacted by my customer today and they were saying that the problem still occurs but there is no "busy tone" anymore.

Since the origin of the problem is a timeout of the call pickup, I was wondering if there is a way to speed up the call pickup by asterisk, because the call is transferred from our provider to our asterisk server, but it is taking too long for our server to accept the call so the caller hangs up, or it simply doesn't connect and the caller hears ringing until he hangs up.

Any ideas would be appreciated as I am at a lost right now.

Thank you,

Philippe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found the problem. The proxy provided by my sip trunk provider needed a port forwarding to our PBX server in the Router. I have tried with another proxy not needing this modification and everything is working fine. I have tried a second line with the port forwarding and it seemed to have solved the problem.

If anyone is having this problem, you might want to try the port 5060 (default) forwarded to your PBX server's IP. It should help you troubleshooting the issue further, if not solving the problem.

Good day